# Is the Tor Project's Roger Dingledine Satoshi Nakamoto, creator of Bitcoin?

Tags: verification

Historically, Roger appears to have been interested in systems with at least a vague resemblance to Bitcoin:

http://archives.seul.org//freehaven/dev/Nov-2001/msg00000.html

While I haven't used stylometry software or other means to try to confirm this, Roger's blog posts and e-mails for the Tor Project seem to bear some stylistic resemblance to Satoshi Nakamoto's e-mails as well.

Has anyone else suspected this?

Others may completely disagree, and this is purely a speculative hunch on my part.  It goes without saying that I would be delighted if Roger considered answering this question directly, since I have the utmost trust in his honesty and integrity.
Cheers!

Comment: Unfortunately too speculative questions which require opinion-based replies do not belong here.

Comment: More than that, questions involving (calling for, contributing to, etc) the compromise of individuals' anonymity do not belong here.